# Delete FB app request with graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After looking at the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)i see the following:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[request_id]?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Though i can't seem to get that to work, what is this DELETE in front of the URL ? 
Could someone show me how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is type of HTTP request

- GET
- POST
- DELETE

so you have to send DELETE request to `https://graph.facebook.com/[request_id]?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: I see, thanks, so would this php code works ? 

file_get_contents('DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[request_id]?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN');

Comment: @silkAdmin: no. It won't. Try to use CURL if you can

Comment: THanks i posted another [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779229/how-to-send-a-delete-request-from-php) about this