# How to send a Delete request from PHP

Tags: php, facebook

The best exemple i have found is:

```
$request_body = 'some data';
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Though this is to deltete an FB app request so the URL should look like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/[request_id]?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Could someone show me how to implement that code for my case ?

Comment: Sorry, what doesn't work here? Don't you just need to change the URL? Please be more specific about what you actually need help with...

Comment: @DaveRandom well i assumed the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body)` should be the parameter of the request. Should i just get rid of this line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body);`

Use

```
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$request_uri.'&access_token='.$access_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```